# Can i pop a message when user clicks on close button in batch script?

Tags: batch-file

**I want to know How to Pop a Message When User clicks the close button in batch file**

I'm looking for a method to pop a message box when user clicks close button in batch.

Like When Users clicks the close button it will pop up a message saying " You just closed " Using VBScript or any other....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am only posting this because you are young and willing to learn.

When you close the cmd window, it stops all execution within that command, nothing triggers any further events. You therefore need to monitor that specific instance with another script. As an example, create a batch file called **mytest.cmd** and enter the following code.

```
@echo off
title Monitor_This
pause
```

create another batch file and let's call it **monitoring.cmd** and enter the following batch/vbscript code:

```
<!-- :
@echo off
:start
tasklist /FI "windowtitle eq Monitor_This" | findstr "cmd.exe">nul 2>&1
if %errorlevel% equ 1 cscript //nologo "%~f0?.wsf" & exit /b
timeout 1 >nul 2>&1
goto :start
exit /b
-->

<job><script language="VBScript">
Set objShell = Wscript.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
objShell.Popup "You closed The Window",, "My Popup"
</script></job>
```

Now run both the scripts. Once they are running, you can close the window that has a title off `Monitor_This` as in the below image:

[image]

Which upon closure will then return:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a command line interface only method:

```
@echo off
if "%~1"=="startchk" goto chk
start "" cmd /c "%~f0 startchk"
rem Rest of code here
goto :eof
:chk
set count=0
for /f "tokens=1 delims= " %%a in ('tasklist ^| findstr /r "[c][m][d][.][e][x][e]"') do set /a count += 1
:chk2
set new=0
for /f "tokens=1 delims= " %%a in ('tasklist ^| findstr /r "[c][m][d][.][e][x][e]"') do set /a new += 1
if %new% lss %count% goto over
goto chk2
:over
msg * "You have closed cmd"
Goto :eof
```